# Ruby on Rails - How to get rid of all special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller:

```rb
 @rugby   = Player.where(sport: 'Rugby')
    @teamsRugby = @rugby.pluck(:name).uniq
    @gamesRugby = RoundRobinTournament.schedule(@teamsRugby)
```

View:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-info">
      <thead class="table-dark">
            <% @gamesRugby.each do |tournement| %>
            <tr>      
              <th>Rugby - Day 1 </th>
              <th>Rugby - Day 2 </th>
              <th>Rugby - Day 3 </th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
            <td><h5><%= tournement %></h5></td>
                    <% end %>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I tried to get rid of characters brackets and quotes.

If i add for example games.first[0] it don't show brackets and quote

```
<td><%= games.first[0] %></td>
```

I am new in RoR.

Comment: Please define which characters are "special characters" (by editing the question). What is your desired return value? Much of the relevant data and code is not shown (`@rugby`, for example) so it not possible for the reader to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment Cary. I add more info.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for but you could use better names for your variables. Calling everything `rugby` will be very confusing. I would call the first `@rugby` something like `@rugby_players` and the `|rugby|` would be clearer if it was `|name|` or something.

Comment: As an aside you should move a lot of this logic to the controller. Making database calls from the view is generally frowned upon.

Comment: put more info into my question.

Answer (score 1):

The special characters in the line you show at the end should not be removed, it's a way for Ruby to show you are dealing with an array (an array of arrays in this case).

Example of a simple array with 3 elements.

```rb
players = ["Jane", "Bill", "Esther"]
```

There are no "special characters" in this example, this is a way to write "I want a list with the names Jane, Bill and Esther" in Ruby.

Example of a more complex one, an array of arrays.

```rb
player_teams = [["Jane", "Team A"], ["Bill", "Team B"], ["Esther", "Team A"]]
```

Your example is missing some square brackets to be a valid array of arrays. If we would like to show only the player names from my `player_teams` example above I could loop over the `player_teams` array in my view.

```rb
<% player_teams.each do |element| %>
  <%= element.first %>
<% end %>
```

Using `element.second` would show the team name.

Try rewriting the `@rugby.each.map(&:name).uniq.map do |rugby|` part, I think the multiple `map` and `each` parts are confusing you.

```rb
<% @rugby.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |name| %>
  <h6><%= name %></h6>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Another way to explain this is that `["Red Rose", "The Shamrocks"], ["All Blacks", "Red Rose"]]` is what you get when you implicitly convert an array of arrays to a string which calls its `to_s` method. This is generally something you never want to do unless you are debugging.

Comment: Resolved by adding join: <td><%=games.join(' - ')  %></td>